# Apt mistakes currently installed `code` package for a different version

Tags: visual-studio-code, package-management, apt, pinning, pop-os

I'm using Pop!_OS 18.04 and VS Code. Unfortunately Pop provides slightly broken `code` packages in its repos and I prefer to use Microsoft-provided `code`. I have their source added and apt sees it. I also have this in `/etc/apt/preferences.d/vs-code-prefer-microsoft`:

```
Package: code
Pin: origin "packages.microsoft.com"
Pin-Priority: 1000
```

`apt-cache policy code` prints this:

```
code:
  Installed: (none)
  Candidate: 1.58.2-1626302803
  Version table:
     1.58.2-1626302803 500
        500 http://apt.pop-os.org/proprietary bionic/main amd64 Packages
        100 /var/lib/dpkg/status
     1.58.2-1626302803 1000
        500 http://packages.microsoft.com/repos/code stable/main amd64 Packages
     1.58.1-1626158276 1000
        500 http://packages.microsoft.com/repos/code stable/main amd64 Packages
…
```

`apt install code` downloads the package from `http://packages.microsoft.com` and installs it successfully, but then `apt-cache policy code` insists that the `apt.pop-os.org` version is installed:

```
code:
  Installed: 1.58.2-1626302803
  Candidate: 1.58.2-1626302803
  Version table:
 *** 1.58.2-1626302803 500
        500 http://apt.pop-os.org/proprietary bionic/main amd64 Packages
        100 /var/lib/dpkg/status
     1.58.2-1626302803 1000
        500 http://packages.microsoft.com/repos/code stable/main amd64 Packages
…
```

And `apt upgrade` wants to "downgrade" it every time. `apt list --upgradable` doesn't mention it though.

I've tried to set priority of `apt.pop-os.org`'s `code` packages to `50` and `apt-cache policy code` reflects this, but the issue is still present.

How can I get this to work reliably? I'd like the Microsoft release to be always preferred.